# How to fade in from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want some text to fade in from bottom to top on scroll.
Right now i have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);
        }
    }); 
  });
});
```

Right now it just fades in, but i want it to fade in from bottom to top.
Any idea's ?

Comment: Could you publish a plunker to understand in more detail the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Right now, i got this: https://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qaD/ but that just fades in at the place where it at atm. i want it to fade in with a sort of animation, so it "Flies" from the bottom of the screen to the place where it belongs.

Comment: I briefly came up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/8rkf4njp/  which matched your description, but then you **added** more info in a comment to clarify the requirement, so it's not quite what you wanted but does "fade in from bottom to top" as per the question (fiddle has long timeouts to show what it's doing).

Comment: Indeed not quite what i wanted, but thanks for trying to help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line of code to your animation options:

JavaScript:

```
if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
    $(this).animate({'opacity':'1', 'margin-top':'50px'}, 500);
}
```

And your CSS to:

```
#container .hideme { 
    opacity:0;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

By doing this, you're not only animating the `opacity` of the element, but also it's `margin-top` property, effectively fading it out when moving 50px to the bottom.

Comment: although its close, its not what i want. When I do this, im adding margin to a element what doesnt need margin.

Comment: This was posted before I saw your comment, i'm playing around the fiddle to try and fix it, hold up ;).

Comment: alright :), btw here is a example of what i want. just found it: http://www.web2feel.com/freeby/scroll-effects/index3.html

Comment: Updated my answer with a working solution in your case. https://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/5841/ new fiddle <=

Comment: Thanks, thats what i wanted :) !